# React Native - Como atribuir valores a uma variável vetor usando Hooks como UseState

Tags: array, react-native, react-hooks

```
const[VetImg,SetVetImg] = useState<any>([''])
```

quero atribuir valores nessa variável

ex:

```
VetImg[0] = 'teste.png'
```

eu sei que a variável é de estado e que tem que ser atribuída pelo `SetVetImg` porém eu quero informar a posição que será atribuída.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se está certo, mas veja se esse código resolve o problema:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [getVetImg, setVetImg] = useState([]);
    
    function addVetImg(value: string) {
        const vet = getVetImg; // talvez seja preciso usar this.getVetImg() ou this.getVetImg dependendo do contexto e ainda acrescentar o tipo da variavel, sendo const vet: string[] = getVetImg
        
        vet.push(value); // ou vet[0] = value;
        
        setVetImg(getVetImg => vet);
    }
    
    // desta forma, pode chamar addVetImg("teste.png"); em qualquer lugar onde for usar esse código
};
```

Comment: deu certo cara muito obrigado !!!!

Comment: de nada, é que agora estou usando mais React, mas já usei React Native e por isso que respondi.